# Can I use multiple same route guards one after another?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

For example,

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    ...
    ...
})
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    ...
    ...
})
```

The official documentation says:

> Global before guards are called in creation order, whenever a
> navigation is triggered.

Before guards are in plural here. But when I use multiple before guards only the first one is called but other are skipped.

The question is not only about the beforeEach but all the navigation guards.

The code with 2 beforeEach that doesn't work:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.name !== 'Logon' && !localStorage.getItem('authToken')) {
    next({ name: 'Logon' })
  } else next()
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.name !== 'Logon' && localStorage.getItem('authToken')) {
    next({ name: 'Homepage' }) //тут будет логика проверки токена на сервере
  } else next()
})
```

Comment: Can you share the content of the beforeEach?

Comment: @tho-masn added an example. Btw your website is looking cool! I like it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported and does not seem like it will be. There are some workarounds mentioned in the thread though such as calling multiple guards within a single guard

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/721